# Does GeoServer support OGC publish/subscribe standard?

Tags: geoserver

According to http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/pubsub only SOAP extension is supported. Does GeoServer's WFS support OGC publish/subscribe standard (GeoServer supports WFS over KVP)?

Answer (score 0):

No, GeoServer only supports WMS, WFS, WCS, WMTS and WPS.